# Inspect Flink operator state in unit tests

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Using Flink's [test harness classes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/testing/) to test my stateful operator, I want to write unit tests that verify that the data that is stored in the operator state is what I expect. However, it seems that I'm not able to do this, and can only call `getOuput` to see what the operator has output and `numKeyedStateEntries` to see how many values are in the state. Is there a way to actually get the values of what is in the state?

Answer (score 1):

There's no (reasonable) way to do that.

You could, hypothetically, write a test that takes a savepoint and then uses the State Processor API to verify the state.

I might argue that testing the values stored in the state would couple the tests too closely to the implementation. Verifying that the results are correct and that state isn't being retained overly long should be enough. But I can agree that having more visibility into the state backend during unit testing would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree with David's comment about how inspecting state creates a tight coupling with implementation. Though sometimes that's useful, if you have complex behavior for setting and/or updating state.

In any case, I believe there is another (unreasonable) way to do this...

1. Create a `MyStateBackend` class that extends `HashMapStateBackend`.

In this class you override `createKeyedStateBackend`, and save the result (it's a `HeapKeyedStateBackend`).

Add a `getStates()` method that returns `List<Tuple2<K, V>>` which are the keyed state values, by calling the saved backend's `getKeys()` and `getOrCreateKeyedState()` methods.

2. When you set up your test harness, call `harness.setStateBackend(your custom state backend)` before calling `harness.setup()` and `harness.open()`.

You should now be able to get/inspect the state.